# AVPlayer observer in Swift - message was received but not handled

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement an observer for `AVPlayer` in pure Swift.

I'm getting the error: "message was received but not handled". Is it because the object argument in the constructor of the observer I'm using is `nil`?

I've placed my example code below:

```
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)


private func deallocObservers(player: AVPlayer) {
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp")

}

//observer for av play
 override  func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "status" {
            print("Change at keyPath = \(keyPath) for \(object)")
        }

        if keyPath == "playbackBufferEmpty" {
            print("playbackBufferEmpty - Change at keyPath = \(keyPath) for \(object)")
        }

        if keyPath == "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" {
            print("Change at keyPath = \(keyPath) for \(object)")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Normally this issue happens when the registered observer deallocates and a KVO event triggers after that. For fixing you need to remove all observers before your object is going to be deallocated.

In your case, you registered for 4 KVO changes and removing only 3. The following KVO observer is not removed anywhere and it is causing the issue.

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
```

Change your `deallocObservers:` method like:

```
private func deallocObservers(player: AVPlayer) {
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
}
```

Comment: I would like to upvote you twice, you have made SO a happy place. :)

Comment: @MidhunMP From where should I call this method, deallocObservers. I tried adding observer in viewWillAppear() and removing them in viewWillDisappear(), but everytime I get this exception ''Cannot remove an observer <....PlayDuckFaceViewController 0x189ce630> for the key path "playbackBufferEmpty" from <AVPlayer 0x189ccfe0> because it is not registered as an observer.''

Comment: @mars: Did you add an observer for `playbackBufferEmpty` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP yes i did. playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem after replacing the method.

```
    override func addObserver(_ observer: NSObject, forKeyPath keyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [], context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {}
```

To

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be relevant to the asked question. Was this intended as an answer to a different question?

Comment: @DaveWeston it's a relevant answer to this particular question - for me it was a different signature issue that led to "message was received but not handled" as per the original post and this answer helped to fix it.